# Building a server side api that can simultaneously transfer data between mobile and web applications

Tags: java, android, mysql, objective-c, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a web application that uses ruby on rails for the server side with mysql, and I want to build an api that will allow a unified interchange between both java for android and objective-C for ios. How should I get started?

Comment: I presume you mean "not over HTTP", right? And if so, why not? And then, what about JSON over HTTP? What kind of data are we talking about? And how much?

Comment: Sorry. For example over the android device I want to be able to add (for example) a small file to a database table for a particular user. I want to make the api with the same functionality in separate languages

Comment: I guess the standard question is, "What have you tried?" There are as many ways to create a server API as there are people and programming languages. To the specifics of what you propose: file systems are pretty good at storing files and databases are pretty good at storing strings (path and filenames). But that doesn't really give me an idea about what you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to creates a server side REST apis which will be consumed by the mobile apps built in android or iOS. APIs are always independent of client side technology that is it can respond to any client. Apis can return data in xml or json format.

Using ruby on rails it is very easy to build REST apis with very fast development. Rails provide very easy ways to return output as json or xml, means you don't need to write separate code for both.

For that in controller you need to add following line on top

```
respond_to :html, :json, :xml
```

And in method definition you can write

```
respond_with(users)
```

It will return specific format based on request url like .json or .xml in URL.